# Flexbox children overflow parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm playing around with flexbox, and my flex-item seems to overflow its parent container. 
What can I do to make sure it will stay inside its confines?

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
}
.flex-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 15%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-item {
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.basicInput {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
#idField {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="flex-container wrap">
    <li class="flex-item">
      <input type="datetime-local" id="dateField" class="basicInput" />
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" id="nameField" class="basicInput" placeholder="  Name:" />
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
      <select id="idType">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="idField" placeholder="  number" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Sorry that it is a bit long :)
But I'm trying to list a few controls vertically, and I want to order two controls on one line.
So an UL holds everything with a flex-direction: column and the LI's orient: horizontal.
But even though the controls are nested in a div with a set width, they still run over its edge. 
Can anyone give me some pointers on what I should do differently :)?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the overflow here.

Comment: I cut off all the bling to make it easier to read, but now it doesn't really show the problem :p    
I want the 2 controls on a line to take up as much space as the other single-line controls.   
But Select is static and idField just takes up too little or overflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do..
but if your'e asking why do the li items are overflowing to the right of the .flex-container, then it is because of the left: 15%; rule you have there.

```
.flex-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  /* this is the problem --- left: 15%; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display:    -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:    -moz-flex;
  display:         flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
```

you can see the effect in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r8a8ojuk/1/

Comment: glad to help. note that you have a lot of redundant and overlapping rules in your css. try reviewing it and clearing some of it up.

Comment: I figured as much, but I find it hard to figure out what everything does, actually :)

Answer (score 0):

have a check

```js
//what's wrong here?
```

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 80%;
}
.flex-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 15%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-item {
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
}
#idType {
width:10%;
}
.basicInput {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
 #idField {
 width:60%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <ul class="flex-container wrap">
            <li class="flex-item">
                <input type="datetime-local" id="dateField" class="basicInput"/> 
            </li>
            <li class="flex-item">
                <input type="text" id="nameField" class="basicInput" placeholder="  Name:"/>
            </li>
           <li class="flex-item">
                <select id="idType">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="idField" placeholder="  number"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: I want the 2 controls to take up as much space as the other ones, but since Select is static in size, the idField overflows or underflows the content div.

Comment: have a check at edit. You can control width by controlling your first 2 items and then 10% is assigned to id type. So if your first 2 fields are 70%, your number field must be 60

Comment: Secondly for pin-point accuracy in size just set idField to 90% and .basicInput to 100% and handle size of div class .content by width attribute.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's a solution.   
But I wanted the Select to take up as much space as it needed, depending on the content, not dictated by me to maybe be too small, with a large font, or something :)

Comment: It is defined in percentage, so it will have enough space in your production code,  you can also put it to 15% of 500px, and it will handle 1000 numbers easily.