# Flexbox: How to make children the same width as the parent?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

In my React Native app, I'm having trouble with making the children the same width as the parent. Please see image below:

[image]

I want the black and the green View to take the whole screen width, therefore get rid of the white background caused by the parent.

How can I achieve this? For example, I tried to apply `width: 100%` to the children, doesn't work. Several solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570687/make-parent-div-same-width-as-child-and-ignore-parent), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769704/flexbox-children-overshooting-the-width-of-the-parent) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964380/flexbox-children-overflow-parent) don't work here.

Here is the code:

```
    <View style={styles.containerWholePage}>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.upper}></View>
        <View style={styles.lower}></View>
      </View>
    </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerWholePage: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  lower: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    flex: 6,
    width: '100%', // doesn't work
  },
  upper: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    flex: 3,
    width: '100%', // doesn't work
  },
});
```

Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: align-items: stretch

Comment: @Pkchekchiseu Tried, this doesn't work >.<

Comment: Put a background on the container the parent `<View>` element and focus on getting those to take up the full width. The children should follow naturally. Start with the top-most container.

Comment: @RyanWheale Now I gave the container a red background plus width:'100%'. The only thing that changes is the white background is now red >.<

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Now give a background to the lone `<View>` element and make sure it is 100% width.

Comment: @RyanWheale Added this. Now the whole screen appears white xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me as you want.

```
    <View style={styles.containerWholePage}>
  {/* <View> */}
    <View style={styles.upper}></View>
    <View style={styles.lower}></View>
  {/* </View> */}
</View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
containerWholePage: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  flex:1,
},
lower: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  backgroundColor: 'green',
 // height:100,
  flex: 6,
  width: '100%', // doesn't work
},
upper: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  backgroundColor: 'black',
   flex: 3,
//height:200,
  width: '100%', // doesn't work
},
```

});

[image: simulator]